# F5 rule deployment and source control

Tags: f5-big-ip

I'm a developer, our Ops team are currently doing F5 rules manually. And nothing is in a source control of any kind.

I want to get to the point where there is a single file in source control, which someone will modify, and then run a script of that single file against the F5 to apply the changes.

What's the best practice on this? I've found a few things, one was Big-pipe SCF. Is that generally how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid developping bigpipe based scripts since it's legacy and removed from v11.

So you have 2 other solutions :

- TMSH : replaces bigpipe but is already available in v10 (not sure in v9) => [Here](http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/TMSH.BigpipeMappings.ashx) are bigpipe/tmsh mappings
- iControl : If you want to do it in the API way => [Here](http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControl.APIReference.ashx) is the API reference

I personnally prefer iControl since I don't want scripts to run on my f5 boxes and it's well documented.

In iControl you will have to use [this](http://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControl.LocalLB__Rule__modify_rule.ashx) to update your rule.

Now with source control, it will depend on when you want the update to be done :
 - When pushing an update to the source control
 - Manually, by pulling the file from source control

In the first case, just add a post update hook script.
In the second case, you'll have to define your workflow more precisely

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of some people [try managing f5 with puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/managing-f5-big-ip-network-devices-with-puppet). Never seen anything in production but "rules [badly done] manually. And nothing is in a source control of any kind." so far :( :(